# What actions make Pitru कुपित (angry)?

Tags: pitru

I am interested in knowing about certain restraints or clear warnings given in Hinduism, that a family/son/daughter should follow, lest the Pitrus be angry.

Follow-up question, what actions (beside sraaddha) make Pitrus happy and content ?

Comment: Where did you find the word 'pitri-dosha'?

Comment: @commonman, I don't remember exactly, but perhaps I heard this word on TV.

Comment: I removed the word Pitru-dosh, since I came to know that it is a different concept.